# If $f$ continuous, $f(0)=f(1)$, are there $x,y$ with $|x-y| = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Then, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, can we show that there must exist $x$ and $y$ such that $|x-y|= \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=f(y)$?

Comment: You have the order wrong.  The way you wrote it, you want a single pair $(x,y)$ that works for all $n$.  You want to say, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ there exist $x$ and $y$ such that ...

Comment: @DonThousand Why do you think that's a counterexample?

Comment: No, it doesn't assume $f$ is differentiable anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(x) = f(x+1/n) - f(x)$, so $g(0) + g(1/n) + \ldots + g((n-1)/n) = 0$.  Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Thank you ....I see how to proceed now.